# What is an efficient way to convert sets to a column index in R?

Tags: performance, algorithm, r, indexing, set

**Overview**

Give a large (nrows > 5,000,000+) data frame, **A**, with string row names and a list of disjoint sets (n = 20,000+), **B**, where each set consists of row names from **A**, what is the best way to create a vector representing the sets in **B** via a unique value?

**Illustration**

Below is an example illustrating this problem:

```
# Input
A <- data.frame(d = rep("A", 5e6), row.names = as.character(sample(1:5e6)))
B <- list(c("4655297", "3177816", "3328423"), c("2911946", "2829484"), ...) # Size 20,000+
```

The desired result would be:

```
# An index of NA represents that the row is not part of any set in B.
> A[,"index", drop = F]
        d index
4655297 A     1
3328423 A     1
2911946 A     2
2829484 A     2
3871770 A    NA
2702914 A    NA
2581677 A    NA
4106410 A    NA
3755846 A    NA
3177816 A     1
```

**Naive Attempt**

Something like this can be achieved using the following method.

```
n <- 0
A$index <- NA
lapply(B, function(x){
  n <<- n + 1
  A[x, "index"] <<- n
})
```

**Problem**

However this is unreasonably slow (several hours) due to indexing A multiple times and is not very R-esque or elegant.

How can the desired result be generated in a quick and efficient manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using base that isn't too bad when compared to your current method.

Sample data:

```
A <- data.frame(d   = rep("A", 5e6),
                set = sample(c(NA, 1:20000), 5e6, replace = TRUE),
                row.names = as.character(sample(1:5e6)))
B <- split(rownames(A), A$set)
```

Base method:

```
system.time({
A$index <- NA
A[unlist(B), "index"] <- rep(seq_along(B), times = lapply(B, length))
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   15.30    0.19   15.50
```

Check:

```
identical(A$set, A$index)
# TRUE
```

For anything faster, I suppose `data.table` will come handy.

Comment: Thank you. Elegant and quick!